# How does Java implement Implicit concurrency apart from Parallel streams

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing

Hi I am a beginner programmer looking at the different variations of Implicit and Explicit concurrency, I see since Java 8 parallel streams have been introduced which allows for parallel concurrency but I don't actually understand how the compiler handles this! Are streams broken up into individual threads and run concurrently? Also what if this causes any errors or issues like what can be seen when using Explicit concurrency.

Comment: Don't you think you're going a bit ahead of yourself if you're a beginner programmer?

Comment: @Kayaman by beginner I mean starting to look into concurrency issues, I understand the basics, starting to construct a program using concurrency. I follow online exercises/tutorials to teach myself.

Answer (score 1):

> I see since Java 8 parallel streams have been introduced which allows
>   for parallel concurrency but I don't actually understand how the
>   compiler handles this! Are streams broken up into individual threads
>   and run concurrently?

I'm not 100% sure, but AFAIK parallel streams use the [fork/join framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) introduced in Java SE 7.

By studying this framework you might get a better understanding how exactly parallel streams work internally.

Comment: It does, but is it used "implicitly" outside of the Parallel streams framework?

Comment: @AndyTurner If you're using parallel sreams then you're using the fork/join framework implicitly. If you're working with the fork/join framework yourself, then you're using it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

> I see since Java 8 parallel streams have been introduced which allows for parallel concurrency but I don't actually understand how the compiler handles this!

The `javac` compile has no idea.  The `parallelStream()` is a method in a library and the compiler has no idea what it does.

> Are streams broken up into individual threads and run concurrently?

The Streams library attempts to break up the work into tasks (around 2 per CPU you have) and these are executed with the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`

> Also what if this causes any errors or issues like what can be seen when using Explicit concurrency

If you throw an Exception this is captured and re-thrown as if it had been thrown in the current thread.

You can try

```
    IntStream.range(0, 16).parallel()
            .forEach(i -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()));
    IntStream.range(0, 16).parallel()
            .forEach(i -> {
                if (Thread.currentThread().getName().endsWith("-2"))
                    throw new RuntimeException();
                Thread.yield();
            });
```

prints

```
Thread[main,5,main]
Thread[main,5,main]
Thread[main,5,main]
Thread[main,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-11,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-13,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-13,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-13,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-8,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4,5,main]
Thread[main,5,main]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:735)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:160)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfInt.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:189)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)
    at java.util.stream.IntPipeline.forEach(IntPipeline.java:404)
    at java.util.stream.IntPipeline$Head.forEach(IntPipeline.java:560)
    at B.main(B.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException
    at B.lambda$main$1(B.java:21)
    at B$$Lambda$2/1452126962.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfInt.accept(ForEachOps.java:205)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$RangeIntSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:110)
    at java.util.Spliterator$OfInt.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:693)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:512)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:291)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1689)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```